python select xpath with data-gs and print text values
I would like to select a span like below and print the value of text (e.g. $1,893 in below sample).
<span data-gs="CjRIaFpZbEZuN0ZPN3dBRDdYYVFCRy0tLS0tLS0tLW95bmQxMUFBQUFBR1lRU3JJR1lqSi1BEg5VQTI2NDV8VUE4ODgjMhoLCODGCxACGgNVU0Q4HHDgxgs=" aria-label="1893 US dollars" role="text">$1,893

</span>

I try below code but output is 0 items selected.
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from time import sleep

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    URL = "https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhooEgoyMDI0LTA2LTEwagwIAhIIL20vMDFfZDRyDAgDEggvbS8wMTkxNBooEgoyMDI0LTA4LTEzagwIAxIIL20vMDE5MTRyDAgCEggvbS8wMV9kNEABSAFwAYIBCwj___________8BmAEB&tfu=EgYIAhAAGAA&hl=en-US&curr=USD"

    driver.get(URL)
    sleep(1)

    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    flights = tree.xpath('//span[@data-gs="CjRIaFpZbEZuN0ZPN3dBRDdYYVFCRy0tLS0tLS0tLW95bmQxMUFBQUFBR1lRU3JJR1lqSi1BEg5VQTI2NDV8VUE4ODgjMhoLCODGCxACGgNVU0Q4HHDgxgs="]')
    print(len(flights))
    for item in flights: 
        print(item.text)
    
    driver.close()
    return

main()



The value of data-gs attribute is not static. It's value is changing for each request so we can use a better xpath to solve identify the price.
The below code snippet is working as expected.
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from time import sleep

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    URL = "https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhooEgoyMDI0LTA2LTEwagwIAhIIL20vMDFfZDRyDAgDEggvbS8wMTkxNBooEgoyMDI0LTA4LTEzagwIAxIIL20vMDE5MTRyDAgCEggvbS8wMV9kNEABSAFwAYIBCwj___________8BmAEB&tfu=EgYIAhAAGAA&hl=en-US&curr=USD"

    driver.get(URL)
    sleep(5)

    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    flights = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'U3gSDe')]/div/div[contains(@class,'YMlIz FpEdX')]/span")
    print(len(flights))
    for item in flights: 
        print(item.text)
    
    driver.close()
    return

main()

Output:
9
$1,963
$2,097
$2,385
$2,657
$2,912
$2,947
$3,079
$3,337
$5,374


Good answer, how can I find the xpath? it's a little bit long for me to understand.

@beetlej You can use chrome extension to write and simplify the xpath. Identify the pattern or static attributes within the tags to write better xpath. pls check this to know some better resources available.
